# Call Javascript to parse HIBC barcode

Tags: javascript

I've found a [Javascript library](https://github.com/chriswjones/HibcBarcodeParsing) that can parse HIBC barcodes - I'm new to Javascript and stuck with getting started and calling the decode function with a barcode parameter to have it decoded and return the result.

I imagine I need to do something like this:

```
var myString = '+A123BJC5D6E71G';
var result = decode (myString);
```

but I'm stuck getting this to run and return a result of the decode function.

```js
/*

 HIBC Decoder

 decode(barcode)
 isMatch(decodedLine1, decodedLine2)
 errors
 type

 */


(function () {
    var error = {
        BarcodeNotAString: 1,
        EmptyBarcode: 2,
        BarcodeNotHIBC: 3,
        InvalidBarcode: 4,
        InvalidDate: 5,
        EmptyCheckCharacter: 6,
        EmptyLinkCharacter: 7,
        InvalidQuantity: 8,
        InvalidLine1: 9
    };

    var type = {
        Concatenated: 1,
        Line1: 2,
        Line2: 3
    };

    function decode(barcode) {
        var decoded = {
            barcode: _.clone(barcode)
        };

        if (!_.isString(barcode)) {
            decoded.error = error.BarcodeNotAString;
            return decoded;
        }

        // remove leading *
        if (barcode.charAt(0) === "*") {
            barcode = barcode.substring(1);
            if (_.isEmpty(barcode)) {
                decoded.error = error.EmptyBarcode;
                return decoded;
            }
        }

        // remove trailing *
        if (barcode.charAt(barcode.length - 1) === "*") {
            barcode = barcode.substring(0, barcode.length - 1);
            if (_.isEmpty(barcode)) {
                decoded.error = error.EmptyBarcode;
                return decoded;
            }
        }

        // Check for + character
        if (barcode.charAt(0) !== "+") {
            decoded.error = error.BarcodeNotHIBC;
            return decoded;
        } else {
            barcode = barcode.substring(1);
        }

        // minimum barcode length
        if (barcode.length < 4) {
            decoded.error = error.InvalidBarcode;
            return decoded;
        }

        // Check and Link characters can contain a "/" so remove them to not affect the split
        var potentialCheckAndLinkCharacters = barcode.substring(barcode.length - 2);
        barcode = barcode.substring(0, barcode.length - 2);

        var array = barcode.split("/");
        if (array.length === 1) {
            if (matchesLetters(array[0].charAt(0))) {
                decoded = processLine1(decoded, type.Line1, array[0] + potentialCheckAndLinkCharacters);
            } else {
                decoded = processLine2(decoded, type.Line2, array[0] + potentialCheckAndLinkCharacters);
            }
            return decoded;
        } else if (array.length == 2) {
            decoded = processLine1(decoded, type.Concatenated, array[0]);
            angular.extend(decoded, processLine2({}, type.Concatenated, array[1] + potentialCheckAndLinkCharacters));
            return decoded;
        } else {
            decoded.error = error.InvalidBarcode;
            return decoded;
        }
    }

    function processLine1(decoded, t, barcode) {
        decoded.type = t;
        if (barcode.length < 4) {
            decoded.error = error.InvalidLine1;
            return decoded;
        }

        decoded.labelerId = barcode.substring(0, 4);
        barcode = barcode.substring(4);

        if (_.isEmpty(barcode)) {
            decoded.error = error.InvalidLine1;
            return decoded;
        }

        // if Concatenated the check char is in the second part of the barcode
        if (decoded.type !== type.Concatenated) {
            decoded.check = barcode.charAt(barcode.length - 1);
            barcode = barcode.substring(0, barcode.length - 1);
            if (_.isEmpty(barcode)) {
                decoded.error = error.InvalidLine1;
                return decoded;
            }
        }

        decoded.uom = parseInt(barcode.charAt(barcode.length - 1), 10);
        barcode = barcode.substring(0, barcode.length - 1);
        if (_.isEmpty(barcode)) {
            decoded.error = error.InvalidLine1;
            return decoded;
        }
        decoded.product = barcode;
        return decoded;
    }

    function processLine2(decoded, type, barcode) {
        decoded.type = type;
        if (barcode.length > 0 && !isNaN(barcode.charAt(0))) {
            if (barcode.length < 5) {
                decoded.error = error.InvalidDate;
                return decoded;
            }
            decoded.date = moment(barcode.substring(0, 5), "YYDDD");
            angular.extend(decoded, decodeLotSerialCheckLink(barcode.substring(5), type, "lot"));
        } else if (barcode.length > 2 && barcode.charAt(0) === "$" && !isNaN(barcode.charAt(1))) {
            angular.extend(decoded, decodeLotSerialCheckLink(barcode.substring(1), type, "lot"));
        } else if (barcode.length > 3 && barcode.substring(0, 2) === "$+" && !isNaN(barcode.charAt(2))) {
            angular.extend(decoded, decodeLotSerialCheckLink(barcode.substring(2), type, "serial"));
        } else if (barcode.length > 3 && barcode.substring(0, 2) === "$$" && !isNaN(barcode.charAt(2))) {
            angular.extend(decoded, decodeLotSerialCheckLink(barcode.substring(2), type, "lot"));
            if (!decoded.error) {
                extractMomentFromString(decoded, "lot", "date");
            }
        } else if (barcode.length > 3 && barcode.substring(0, 3) === "$$+") {
            angular.extend(decoded, decodeLotSerialCheckLink(barcode.substring(3), type, "serial"));
            extractMomentFromString(decoded, "serial", "date");
        } else {
            decoded.error = error.InvalidBarcode;
        }

        return decoded;
    }

    function decodeLotSerialCheckLink(string, barcodeType, propertyName) {
        if (_.isEmpty(string)) {
            return {
                error: error.EmptyCheckCharacter
            };
        }
        var decoded = {};

        decoded.lot = string;
        string = extractQuantityFromString(decoded, string, "quantity");

        // Check character
        decoded.check = string.substring(string.length - 1);
        string = string.substring(0, string.length - 1);

        // LotOrSerial and LinkCharacter
        if (barcodeType === type.Line2) {
            if (_.isEmpty(string)) {
                return {
                    error: error.EmptyLinkCharacter
                };
            }
            decoded.link = string.substring(string.length - 1);
            decoded[propertyName] = string.substring(0, string.length - 1);
        } else {
            decoded[propertyName] = string;
        }

        return decoded;
    }

    function extractMomentFromString(object, stringProperty, momentProperty) {
        var string = object[stringProperty];
        if (!_.isString(string) || _.isEmpty(string)) {
            return;
        }

        var hibcDateFormat = parseInt(string.substring(0, 1), 10);
        if (!_.isNumber(hibcDateFormat)) {
            object["error"] = error.InvalidDate;
            return;
        }

        var dateFormat;
        switch (hibcDateFormat) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
                dateFormat = "MMYY";
                break;
            case 2:
                dateFormat = "MMDDYY";
                break;
            case 3:
                dateFormat = "YYMMDD";
                break;
            case 4:
                dateFormat = "YYMMDDHH";
                break;
            case 5:
                dateFormat = "YYDDD";
                break;
            case 6:
                dateFormat = "YYDDDHH";
                break;
            case 7:
                // no date following the 7

                object[stringProperty] = string.substring(1);
                return;
            default:
                // no date char
                return;
        }

        if (hibcDateFormat > 1) {
            string = string.substring(1);
        }

        if (string.length < dateFormat.length) {
            object["error"] = error.InvalidDate;
            return;
        }

        object[momentProperty] = moment(string.substring(0, dateFormat.length), dateFormat);
        object[stringProperty] = string.substring(dateFormat.length);
    }

    function extractQuantityFromString(object, string, quantityProperty) {
        var i = parseInt(string.charAt(0), 10);
        if (!_.isNumber(i)) {
            return string;
        }

        var length;
        switch (i) {
            case 8:
                length = 2;
                break;
            case 9:
                length = 5;
                break;
            default:
                // no qty
                return string;
        }

        string = string.substring(1);
        var quantity = parseInt(string.substring(0, length), 10);
        string = string.substring(length);

        if (!_.isNumber(quantity)) {
            object["error"] = error.InvalidQuantity;
            return string;
        }

        object[quantityProperty] = quantity;

        return string;
    }

    function isMatch(line1, line2) {
        if (!_.isObject(line1) || line1.type !== type.Line1 || !_.isObject(line2) || line2.type !== type.Line2) {
            return false;
        }

        return line1.check === line2.link;
    }

    function matchesLetters(character) {
        var letters = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
        return character.match(letters);
    }

    function matchesNumbers(character) {
        var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
        return character.match(numbers);
    }

    /*
     Expose hibc
     */

    this["HIBC"] = {
        decode: decode,
        isMatch: isMatch,
        type: type,
        errors: error
    };

}).call(this);
```

Comment: "*I've found a Javascript library*" - consider reading its documentation. It should be explained in there how to invoke the `decode` method. If you have trouble understanding the documentation, please link it and quote the problematic part in your question.

Comment: There's no documentation unfortunately apart from the .js file itself - here's the link to the Github repo where I found it: https://github.com/chriswjones/HibcBarcodeParsing

Comment: Wow, that's pretty bad user documentation. Anyway, [the tests should give you an idea](https://github.com/chriswjones/HibcBarcodeParsing/blob/master/JavaScript/hibc.spec.js#L18).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uff, this is rough. The hibc.js depends on lodash, moment and angular.extend, which have to be available in the global scope. If it is not an Angular project, you can mock the dependency.

In node, this works for me (file has to be a module file, i.e. `test.mjs`, install requirements with `npm i lodash moment`):

```
import hibc from './hibc.js' // local copy of hibc.js
import _ from 'lodash'
import moment from 'moment'

// put requirements into global scope 
global._ = _
global.moment = moment
global.angular = {extend: _.extend}

console.log(hibc.HIBC.decode("*+Z999009993020351/05271C"))
```

Output is:

```js
{
  barcode: '*+Z999009993020351/05271C',
  type: 1,
  labelerId: 'Z999',
  uom: 1,
  product: '00999302035',
  date: Moment<2005-09-28T00:00:00+02:00>,
  lot: '',
  check: 'C'
}
```

In the browser, it is a bit easier, since libraries are always imported into global scope:

```html
<script src="file:///home/bl1rt/Public/repos/hbic/hibc.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.angular = {extend: _.extend}
    console.log(HIBC.decode("*+Z999009993020351/05271C"))
</script>
```

But both is pretty gnarly. If I were you, I would update the local copy of `hibc.js` to make it work in your environment:

- replace `angular.extend()` with lodash's `_.extend()`
- maybe replace the lodash function altogether with builtins
- if you want to use it in node, add the imports into the file and turn the iife into an export:

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import moment from 'moment'

/*

 HIBC Decoder

 decode(barcode)
 isMatch(decodedLine1, decodedLine2)
 errors
 type

 */


var error = {
    BarcodeNotAString: 1,
    EmptyBarcode: 2,
    BarcodeNotHIBC: 3,
    InvalidBarcode: 4,
    InvalidDate: 5,
    EmptyCheckCharacter: 6,
    EmptyLinkCharacter: 7,
    InvalidQuantity: 8,
    InvalidLine1: 9
};

var type = {
    Concatenated: 1,
    Line1: 2,
    Line2: 3
};

function decode(barcode) {
    var decoded = {
        barcode: _.clone(barcode)
    };

    if (!_.isString(barcode)) {
        decoded.error = error.BarcodeNotAString;
        return decoded;
    }

    // remove leading *
    if (barcode.charAt(0) === "*") {
        barcode = barcode.substring(1);
        if (_.isEmpty(barcode)) {
            decoded.error = error.EmptyBarcode;
            return decoded;
        }
    }

    // remove trailing *
    if (barcode.charAt(barcode.length - 1) === "*") {
        barcode = barcode.substring(0, barcode.length - 1);
        if (_.isEmpty(barcode)) {
            decoded.error = error.EmptyBarcode;
            return decoded;
        }
    }

    // Check for + character
    if (barcode.charAt(0) !== "+") {
        decoded.error = error.BarcodeNotHIBC;
        return decoded;
    } else {
        barcode = barcode.substring(1);
    }

    // minimum barcode length
    if (barcode.length < 4) {
        decoded.error = error.InvalidBarcode;
        return decoded;
    }

    // Check and Link characters can contain a "/" so remove them to not affect the split
    var potentialCheckAndLinkCharacters = barcode.substring(barcode.length - 2);
    barcode = barcode.substring(0, barcode.length - 2);

    var array = barcode.split("/");
    if (array.length === 1) {
        if (matchesLetters(array[0].charAt(0))) {
            decoded = processLine1(decoded, type.Line1, array[0] + potentialCheckAndLinkCharacters);
        } else {
            decoded = processLine2(decoded, type.Line2, array[0] + potentialCheckAndLinkCharacters);
        }
        return decoded;
    } else if (array.length == 2) {
        decoded = processLine1(decoded, type.Concatenated, array[0]);
        _.extend(decoded, processLine2({}, type.Concatenated, array[1] + potentialCheckAndLinkCharacters));
        return decoded;
    } else {
        decoded.error = error.InvalidBarcode;
        return decoded;
    }
}

function processLine1(decoded, t, barcode) {
    decoded.type = t;
    if (barcode.length < 4) {
        decoded.error = error.InvalidLine1;
        return decoded;
    }

    decoded.labelerId = barcode.substring(0, 4);
    barcode = barcode.substring(4);

    if (_.isEmpty(barcode)) {
        decoded.error = error.InvalidLine1;
        return decoded;
    }

    // if Concatenated the check char is in the second part of the barcode
    if (decoded.type !== type.Concatenated) {
        decoded.check = barcode.charAt(barcode.length - 1);
        barcode = barcode.substring(0, barcode.length - 1);
        if (_.isEmpty(barcode)) {
            decoded.error = error.InvalidLine1;
            return decoded;
        }
    }

    decoded.uom = parseInt(barcode.charAt(barcode.length - 1), 10);
    barcode = barcode.substring(0, barcode.length - 1);
    if (_.isEmpty(barcode)) {
        decoded.error = error.InvalidLine1;
        return decoded;
    }
    decoded.product = barcode;
    return decoded;
}

function processLine2(decoded, type, barcode) {
    decoded.type = type;
    if (barcode.length > 0 && !isNaN(barcode.charAt(0))) {
        if (barcode.length < 5) {
            decoded.error = error.InvalidDate;
            return decoded;
        }
        decoded.date = moment(barcode.substring(0, 5), "YYDDD");
        _.extend(decoded, decodeLotSerialCheckLink(barcode.substring(5), type, "lot"));
    } else if (barcode.length > 2 && barcode.charAt(0) === "$" && !isNaN(barcode.charAt(1))) {
        _.extend(decoded, decodeLotSerialCheckLink(barcode.substring(1), type, "lot"));
    } else if (barcode.length > 3 && barcode.substring(0, 2) === "$+" && !isNaN(barcode.charAt(2))) {
        _.extend(decoded, decodeLotSerialCheckLink(barcode.substring(2), type, "serial"));
    } else if (barcode.length > 3 && barcode.substring(0, 2) === "$$" && !isNaN(barcode.charAt(2))) {
        _.extend(decoded, decodeLotSerialCheckLink(barcode.substring(2), type, "lot"));
        if (!decoded.error) {
            extractMomentFromString(decoded, "lot", "date");
        }
    } else if (barcode.length > 3 && barcode.substring(0, 3) === "$$+") {
        _.extend(decoded, decodeLotSerialCheckLink(barcode.substring(3), type, "serial"));
        extractMomentFromString(decoded, "serial", "date");
    } else {
        decoded.error = error.InvalidBarcode;
    }

    return decoded;
}

function decodeLotSerialCheckLink(string, barcodeType, propertyName) {
    if (_.isEmpty(string)) {
        return {
            error: error.EmptyCheckCharacter
        };
    }
    var decoded = {};

    decoded.lot = string;
    string = extractQuantityFromString(decoded, string, "quantity");

    // Check character
    decoded.check = string.substring(string.length - 1);
    string = string.substring(0, string.length - 1);

    // LotOrSerial and LinkCharacter
    if (barcodeType === type.Line2) {
        if (_.isEmpty(string)) {
            return {
                error: error.EmptyLinkCharacter
            };
        }
        decoded.link = string.substring(string.length - 1);
        decoded[propertyName] = string.substring(0, string.length - 1);
    } else {
        decoded[propertyName] = string;
    }

    return decoded;
}

function extractMomentFromString(object, stringProperty, momentProperty) {
    var string = object[stringProperty];
    if (!_.isString(string) || _.isEmpty(string)) {
        return;
    }

    var hibcDateFormat = parseInt(string.substring(0, 1), 10);
    if (!_.isNumber(hibcDateFormat)) {
        object["error"] = error.InvalidDate;
        return;
    }

    var dateFormat;
    switch (hibcDateFormat) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            dateFormat = "MMYY";
            break;
        case 2:
            dateFormat = "MMDDYY";
            break;
        case 3:
            dateFormat = "YYMMDD";
            break;
        case 4:
            dateFormat = "YYMMDDHH";
            break;
        case 5:
            dateFormat = "YYDDD";
            break;
        case 6:
            dateFormat = "YYDDDHH";
            break;
        case 7:
            // no date following the 7

            object[stringProperty] = string.substring(1);
            return;
        default:
            // no date char
            return;
    }

    if (hibcDateFormat > 1) {
        string = string.substring(1);
    }

    if (string.length < dateFormat.length) {
        object["error"] = error.InvalidDate;
        return;
    }

    object[momentProperty] = moment(string.substring(0, dateFormat.length), dateFormat);
    object[stringProperty] = string.substring(dateFormat.length);
}

function extractQuantityFromString(object, string, quantityProperty) {
    var i = parseInt(string.charAt(0), 10);
    if (!_.isNumber(i)) {
        return string;
    }

    var length;
    switch (i) {
        case 8:
            length = 2;
            break;
        case 9:
            length = 5;
            break;
        default:
            // no qty
            return string;
    }

    string = string.substring(1);
    var quantity = parseInt(string.substring(0, length), 10);
    string = string.substring(length);

    if (!_.isNumber(quantity)) {
        object["error"] = error.InvalidQuantity;
        return string;
    }

    object[quantityProperty] = quantity;

    return string;
}

function isMatch(line1, line2) {
    if (!_.isObject(line1) || line1.type !== type.Line1 || !_.isObject(line2) || line2.type !== type.Line2) {
        return false;
    }

    return line1.check === line2.link;
}

function matchesLetters(character) {
    var letters = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    return character.match(letters);
}

function matchesNumbers(character) {
    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
    return character.match(numbers);
}
/*
 Expose hibc
 */

export const HIBC = {
    decode: decode,
    isMatch: isMatch,
    type: type,
    errors: error
};
```

Now you can import and use it as:

```
import {HIBC} from './hibc.mjs'
console.log(HIBC.decode("*+Z999009993020351/05271C"))
```

(Depending on your setup, you might have to turn it into a module, i.e. hibc.mjs)